# Facebox not working after jQuery scrollExtend

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, facebox

I am using [Facebox](http://github.com/defunkt/facebox) in my website. It works fine except when calling jQuery scrollExtend, in which case it doesn't work in appended scripts after calling scrollExtend.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed that error:).I was applying facebox to anchor tags having relative attribute facebox.In header file I am calling facebox function to apply face box to feeds before using scrollExtend. Previous code was like this

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#newsFeedMainID").scrollExtend({ 
        "target": "div#newsFeedSubID",          
        "url": "loadNewsFeed.php", 
        "newElementClass": "list_item more_content",            
        beforeStart: function(){
            $("#loadNewsFeed").show();              
                return true;
        },
        onSuccess: function(){
            return true;
        }                   
    });
```

});

I just changed that code as follows

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#newsFeedMainID").scrollExtend({ 
        "target": "div#newsFeedSubID",          
        "url": "loadNewsFeed.php", 
        "newElementClass": "list_item more_content",            
        beforeStart: function(){
            $("#loadNewsFeed").show();              
            $("'a[rel *=facebox]").removeAttr("rel");
            return true;
        },
        onSuccess: function(){
            $("#loadNewsFeed").hide();              
              $('a[rel *=facebox]').facebox({
                loadingImage : 'js/facebox/loading.gif',
                closeImage   : 'js/facebox/closelabel.png'
              })
            return true;
        }                   
    });
```

});

It works now :)